# How to break the undo chain from a function call? (not Ctrl-G)

Tags: undo

When undoing you can press Ctrl-G to redo.

This runs `keyboard-quit` which signals `quit`.

However this isn't convenient because as far as I know you can't run commands *after* keyboard-quit.

Is there a more direct way to break the undo chain, or a way to run `keyboard-quit` so you can keep calling functions after it?

---

I tried this for an undo/redo that doesn't require explicit Ctrl-G.

```el
(defvar-local my-undo-is-redo nil)

(defun my-redo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-quit t))
    (unless my-undo-is-redo (with-local-quit (keyboard-quit)))
    ;; redo continued...
    (undo)
    (setq my-undo-is-redo t)))

(defun my-undo-only ()
  (interactive)
  (undo-only)
  (setq my-undo-is-redo nil))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "u") 'my-undo-only)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-r") 'my-redo)
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are aiming at. Note that there is the construction `(let ((inhibit-quit t)) (with-local-quit ... (command-where-quit-might-occur) ...) (function-after-it))`.

Comment: Something like this could work, but it didn't in my tests, edited question.

Comment: I think you just need `(setq last-command 'ignore)` to break the the undo chain. But then the redo chain gets broken too so it doesn't work very well...

Comment: Note, that there is [undo-tree](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html) supporting undo/redo in the undo tree by `<up>`, `<down>`, `<left>`, and `<right>`. I switched to `undo-tree` and never went back. Always when I test code with `emacs -Q` I notice how much I like undo-tree more than the standard undo system of Emacs.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [redo+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RedoPlus)? Or maybe you should go all the way to undo-tree...

Comment: Both redo+ and undo-tree are buggy, I'd just like a quick way to reverse direction - http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_best_redo_mode.html & https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/85t95p/undo_tree_unrecognized_entry_in_undo_list/

Comment: @npostavs - this works, you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undo` decides to chain or not based on the value of `last-command`, so if you just set it to something other than `undo` it will break the chain.  No need for quitting.

```el
(defun my-redo ()
  (interactive)
  (setq last-command 'ignore)
  ;; redo continued...
  (undo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's undo/redo for evil mode using the method described by @npostavs.

```el
(defun my-redo ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Break undo chain, avoid having to press Ctrl-G.
  (when (string= last-command 'undo)
    (setq last-command 'ignore))
  (undo))

(defun my-undo ()
  (interactive)
  (undo-only)
  (setq this-command 'undo))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "u") 'my-undo)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-r") 'my-redo))
```